# How do I change the color of the output in zsh?

Tags: terminal, zsh

For example, if I want the output of all commands to be red, how do I do it? Scenario- you type "ls" and then all the file it lists should be red in color. And this should continue for the next commands as well as long as I don't change the color to some other color.

Comment: It's probably easier to set your terminal default to your desired output color, then use `zle_highlight` to modify how the *input* appears.

Comment: (The appearance of the output is controlled by whatever program produces the output; it's not "filtered" through `zsh`. The input, however, *is* controlled by the line editor `zle` built in to `zsh`.)

Comment: The shell does not really **know** about colours. When your terminal is receiving in the output of the commands embedded codes to change the colour, the terminal colorizes it. zsh only helps to a certain extent to embed such colour codes, for instance during configuration of the prompt. If you just want to change the normal foreground colour of your terminal, this would be set up inside the terminal. If you are specifically concerned about colouring the output from `ls`, this can be controlled via the environment variable `LS_COLORS`.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) helps you to configure the colouring by yourself.  Just  print the respective colour code right before the command you want to colorize (make sure that no terminal prompt is displayed in between, as this likely will reset the colour).

Answer (score 1):

The `-P` option of the `print` command allows you to let zsh do prompt expansion and with this insert colour changing codes into the output. For instance,

```
print -P %F{red]'; cat myfile
```

prefixes the ansi escape code for *red* to the output produced by `cat`. The effect will be that `myfile` is printed in red (or whatever you have told your terminal what the colour *red* is supposed to be; most terminals can be configured to map ansi colour codes to arbitrary RGB colours).

For setting the background colour, use `%K` instead of `%F`.

Answer (score 0):

The first answer had a little typo.

That is what he meant:
`print -P '%F{red}'; cat /path/to/file`

the same would work in a shell script if you define `#!/bin/zsh` at the beginning of the file.

**Example**:

```
#!/bin/zsh
print -P '%F{red} text-text-text';
```

Output: `text-text-text` *in red*

**Perfect Example**:
https://gist.github.com/HaleTom/89ffe32783f89f403bba96bd7bcd1263
Have a look here, than it should be clear, how it works :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).